# How to attach event listener to document/window and make sure event.target is the document

Tags: javascript, typescript, mouseevent

I'm trying to attach a mousedown event listener to the window. This event listener sets body `pointer-events` to none. Then I have a mouseup listener which sets pointer events back to "auto".

Problem: I need the same `event.target` for mousedown and mouseup, or specifically I need my target for mousedown to be `HTML`.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-stonebraker-3mut9?file=/src/App.js

If you mousedown the `<rect />`, you can see in the console, `event.target` is `rect`.
Since now pointer events are disabled, `mouseup`'s `event.target` is `HTML`.

How can I make sure that `mousedown` `event.target` is `HTML`?

Comment: unsure how that would be possible if you set pointer events.... If you want to be the HTML, why do you need to reference event.target?

Comment: I'm implementing `@visx/zoom` for Pan/Zoom and I want to make sure panning works even when cursor leaves the browser (while mousing down). `event.target` is always HTML when mousemoving outside of the browser, and visx uses `event.target.getBoundingClientRect` to calculate panning. So I've got it all working but since the mousedown target is different after mousedown, there is a slight jump whenever it goes from mousedown to mousemove, which is very annoying.

Comment: So why are you not just reading the HTML to start? Why rely on the target? Use srcElement?

Comment: Because I'm just passing the event to visx method `zoom.dragStart(event)`, and didnt necessarily want to change their implementation... But maybe there's no other way. I guess you'Re right, if the implementation used `currentTarget` instead of `target` there wouldnt be a problem.